# UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey

Tags: ios, keyboard, constants

What is the diffefence between UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey and UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey ?

Does that mean that the "begin" one returns a value that differs from what the "end" one returns?

Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey will return the frame of the keyboard before the animation begins. The UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey will return the frame of the keyboard after the animation has completed. As an example, take the following snippet of code:

```
NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
CGRect beginFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect endFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
```

If you were to print the values of `beginFrame` and `endFrame` in the debug window, you might find something like this:

```
(gdb) print beginFrame
$1 = {
   origin = {
     x = 0, 
     y = 480
   }, 
   size = {
     width = 320, 
     height = 216
   }
 }
 (gdb) print endFrame
 $2 = {
   origin = {
     x = 0, 
     y = 264
   }, 
   size = {
     width = 320, 
     height = 216
   }
 }
```

So on an iPhone, this is showing that the keyboard will animate in from the bottom of the screen. The size of the keyboard doesn't change (as expected), but the y co-ordinates show the beginning and ending position of the keyboard.

Comment: Before keyboard start moving, it should be y=0. I don't understand why it is 480. -480 makes more sense cause keyboard is not on the view...